# What's an easy to get explanation for the difference between built-in types and objects?

Tags: python, ruby

I'm referring to [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/RubyPythonMacOSX.html). I can't fully understand this sentence:

> While Python code can contain both objects and built-in types, in Ruby everything is an object. There are no primitive or built-in types, such as integers. Thus anything in Ruby code can accept messages.

What's the difference between for example Ruby's [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html) and Python's [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)?

I mean: Integer, String, etc. are in Ruby available without any imports or similar as well. Where is the difference?

Can someone give an easy explanation what built-in types are and how they differ from the classes of the standard library?

Comment: That's misleading because it conflates "built-in types" (which I would take to mean types that are part of the language) with "primitive" types (which Python doesn't have) - you can call a method on a (built-in, non-primitive) `int`, to take their example, `(1).bit_length()`.

Comment: "...in Ruby everything is an object." is oft written but is not quite right. Keywords, blocks and many operators, for example, are not objects.

Comment: In Ruby, you have the _core library_, which is available without requiring it, and the _standard library_, which comes with Ruby, but needs a `require` statement. For instance, `Array` is in core, while `Set` is in the std-lib and needs a `require 'set'`. Aside from this, there is no much difference. You can add new methods to both `Array` and `Set`, if you like.

Comment: @user1934428 as of 3.2 `Set` is part of core [Feature](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16989)

Comment: @engineersmnky : Since when? I was checking the docs for Ruby 1.9.3 (which is used in our project), and in this old version at least, it was still in std-lib. We have to do `require "set"` in order to use it. I did not expect **this** to change, so I haven't check more recent Ruby versions.

Comment: @user1934428 in 3.2 as mentioned. That being said 1.9.3 is 9 years old, so referencing those docs would not apply to many recent ruby implementations